# Word for terminology related to mathematical premises

Tags: terminology, mathematics

I have seen some mathematical texts that use words like *Lemma, Theorem, Corollary*, etc.  What would be the appropriate description of such terms?  Do they fall under some linguistic category?  Is there any general term associated with these kinds of premises?

Comment: I think the only linguistic category is "nouns". I don't think linguistics generally deals with the spheres of knowledge that words reference, unless it has some impact on the way the words are used in language.

Comment: But if you think linguists have some special terminology for them, [linguistics.se] would be the place to ask.

Comment: Do you want a hypernym or more general word covering the meaning of the terms, all of which mean something similar (all describe true statements or results such as you might prove using mathematical reasoning)? If not, you'll have to tell us what makes them form a class, and what words aren't in the class, and why. This seems a question for mathematics or philosophy SE unless you have a question that's actually about the English language.

Comment: Correct, Looking to see if there can be a more general word covering them (I use `assertions` or `premises`).

Comment: Some things like `Theorems` are statements that are true.  Whereas others (e.g. `Proposition`) could turn out to be false.

Comment: There is a distinction between a lemma and a theorem, and between a theorem and an axiom. But only for mathematicians. All of them are names for different (to a mathematician) types of true statements (though "theorem" is often used for statements that are widely believed but not yet proven -- Fermat's Last Theorem was so-called for centuries before Wilde proved it).

Comment: Now this doesn't seem like a linguistics question. Try asking in [math.se] if mathematicians have a general term for all these items. In general, when you're looking for technical terms, it's best to ask the members of the group that uses it.

Comment: Why should terminology related to mathematical premises not simply be 'mathematical terms'?